# How to get the post ID's of the five most recent posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, id

How can I get an array with the post ID's of the five most recent posts? I need it to exclude those posts from a WP_Query / get_posts().

I need a WP_query that skips the first five posts and starts with the sixth. I've been trying this for some time, so if you have a solution for that: very appreciated!

Comment: Might your question not, therefore, be, "how do I skip the first five posts with `WP_query`. I've tried..."?

Comment: Hi @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt thanks for your suggestions! Actually, both questions are mine ;). I've been messing around with this problem for some time and I've tried a lot of different things. I first asked the question of excluding latest x posts, but because I did not get a reply (yet), I figured out that it could also be done by first getting the post id's themselves and then excluding them. So for that I made a different question, hoping that there are people that know how to do that. But in the end it's all about the same problem. All suggestions for fixing this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I understand your frustration. Answers can be slow to arrive here.

Comment: What you are looking for is called offset.

Comment: But isn't offset about pagination and not about posts itself?

Comment: Or is there some requirement so that it works for posts themselves?

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt I got it working, indeed using the offset parameter. Thanks a lot for thinking along! Sb answered the question you posted a link to yesterday in the above comments.

Comment: happy to help. I'm glad you got your answer.